# Treating gun control like types of driver licenses, i.e. Class A, B, C, D, M, and V

Tags: united-states, guns

I'm just curious if there is an organization that is active that is trying to implement a gun-control system akin to the hierarchy of driving privileges?

For example, an initial level that gives people access to bolt-action rifles and pump-action shotguns, then after a successful period allows the ability to apply for handgun ownership, then after a successful period allows the ownership of semi-auto rifles and semi-auto shotguns.

Is there any organisation trying to enact such a law?

Comment: This kind of question seems more of a match for Worldbuilding.se than here.

Comment: Given that the U.S. government today is not allowed to even track the sales of guns, this would be a monumental step.  The gun manufacturing industry, via the NRA, has an out-sized influence over the discussion here.  Of course in their opinion, the solution to all problems is more people purchasing their products.

Comment: @Tal The NRA doesn't represent the firearm manufacturing industry; instead, the National Shooting Sports Federation, NSSF, does. While the NRA does receive some financial backing from firearms manufactures, it represents the American Gun owners.

Comment: @Drunk Cynic Aside from only having a small minority of gun owners as members... The positions that they take simply do not represent "American gun owners".  They regularly undercut attempts to enforce even the most basic checks while simultaneously claiming that enforcement of current laws is the solution.  Their "members" control the NRA in the same sense that a Facebook user controls Facebook.  Their audience is the product.  They get paid to manipulate people.  Largely by gun manufacturers, who also sometimes include membership for free with purchase of a firearm.

Comment: @Tal: Sorry, but you are flat-out wrong.   Whie no organization can ever be 100% aligned with all its members, if it is too far off base, members will drop out.  Likewise, there are many gun owners (I'm one) who are in general agreement with the NRA's positions, but who are not members.  There are even some who even further, holding that most current laws  (even the ones the NRA supports) & background checks are unconstitutional,

Comment: It's worth noting that this is nothing like driving privileges.  There is no requirement that someone get one type of driving license to get another.  The tests are simply different.

Comment: @Tal Who exactly do you think the members are then? Why would people continue to be members if they were unhappy with NRA positions?

Comment: @Andy Because they get benefits from lots of other places?  Especially ones related to the firearm industry?  https://benefits.nra.org/  Why do people join AAA?  Because they fervently agree with their political positions?  Many probably got their initial membership for free from purchasing a firearm, which is another form of direct payment from the gun manufacturer to the NRA.

Comment: @Tal LOL.  Ya, ok.. someone doesn't support the NRA positions but will sign up for a magazine and a few discounts?  As far as free membership goes, you have to fill out a form and send it in, you're not automatically made a member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to my knowledge on a national level.  There is only so much the Feds can do without amending the Constitution.  There are four states that require licenses to buy any firearm (Hawaii, Illinois, Massachusetts, and New Jersey) and an additional four that require a license for handguns only (Iowa, Michigan, Nebraska, and North Carolina).  Why Handguns only?  Well, handguns are actually the classification of firearms most likely to be used in firearm related crimes.  The most recent numbers I've seen attribute 5,600 criminal deaths to handguns, where as only 246 are attributable to semi-automatic rifles and slightly fewer were attributed to Shotguns/Bolt Action Rifles.

While many nations do have liscensing systems for gun ownership for various purposes, this may not be an easy law to implement in the states due to being an unreasonable restriction under the 2nd Amendment (I'm not aware of any states challenges rising far enough to test that validity) and would be hard to pass, let alone defend.  States that have strict guidelines and are "May Issue" states (meaning that even if you meet all the qualifications, the decision maker can still say no because... reasons...) tend to reverse the decision on first appeal as they would rather quietly give you the license than let the complaint rise to a level where a court is ruling against the law.

At this time, I'm not aware of any group actively calling for this on a national level, though the Federal Government does not have much of a say in automotive licensing so if there is a group working towards this, they would be working at a more local level.

Comment: If I understand correctly there are other states (or at least one) that require a license for all firearms purchases in a part of their territory (I'm thinking of New York City).

Comment: @phoog:  Yes, but they are currently being challenged as a violation of 2nd Amendment Rights.  These laws are made by the City, not the State.

Comment: The laws may be enacted by the city government, but its power to enact the laws is delegated to it by the state.

Comment: @phoog A number of States have Preemption clauses in their laws restricting lower authorities from establishing additional gun laws.

Comment: @DrunkCynic that comment seems to reinforce my point that ultimately the State of NY is responsible for restrictions that do or don't exist in the City of NY: it has delegated some authority to legislate and it has not pre-empted the establishment of additional gun laws. Hszmv: I can't find any references mentioning current 2nd amendment challenges; do you have any? I've only found mention of some challenges from a few years ago that went nowhere in the courts.

Comment: @phoog not disagreeing with you, just adding context.

Comment: @phoog:  http://www.nysrpa.org/nysrpa-v-nyc-title-38/ :  It lost in initial trial, but is currently appealed to 2nd Circuit court.

Comment: @phoog:  And you are right.  California, for example, does not mandate a required training course for gun ownership as every locality already had enacted such laws.

Comment: @hszmv the second circuit panel decided in favor of the city in late February. I don't see any evidence that NYSRPA is appealing that.  Do you know?

Comment: @phoog:  Not that I am aware of (I wasn't aware it was decided).  They could still be in the phase of assessing if they can get a better hearing upon further appeal.

Comment: @hszmv perhaps they are waiting for the outcome of that assessment before updating their web page.

Comment: @phoog:  That was my thought.  It's barely a two months, so they could have some time to file.  Got a link to something Re: the decision?  Just for my own curiosity.

Comment: I found a couple of news articles by searching for "nysrpa v city of new york" and "nysrpa v nyc," one of which quoted a bit from the decision.  You can get the full decision by searching at http://www.ca2.uscourts.gov/decisions.html.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such organization.  If there were, it would face a practical obstacle, in addition to the legal (Second Amendment &c) and psychological (just another scheme from the gun grabbers!) ones.

The problem is that the purposes for which weapons are owned aren't nearly so neatly graduated.  A sport hunter might be perfectly satisfied with a bolt-action rifle or shotgun.  Someone who wants an easily-carried weapon for self-defense (or other purposes) is generally going to need a pistol: a long gun simply isn't practical in many situations.

For instance, it's quite usual for my female riding companions to carry pistols out on the trail.  (Even though AFAIK none of them hunt, or own long guns.)  They could take a rifle in a saddle scabbard, but say they happen to be charged by a bear, their horse panics, bucks you off, and goes running down the trail with their rifle?  (Not a contrived example: it happened to a friend last fall.)

Likewise, the person who wants a semi-auto rifle might have absolutely no need or desire to own a pistol.  So you're imposing burdens of cost & time by requiring people to buy unneeded/unwanted weapons and wait for unstated periods before being able to get what they do need.

Comment: The system OP is talking about is already implemented in some European states. E.g. in Czech Republic there's 5 license classifications and additional licensing barriers for the most dangerous weapons. Most people simply apply for all 5 at once since it's the same test.

Comment: @JonathanReez: In what alternate universe do European states have a problem with imposing burdensome regulations on their citizens?  (Besides, the OP specifies imposing a delay between various types.)

Answer (score -4):

Gun-rights advocates might not mind such legislation if they believed that it would never be used to restrict the rights of individuals who have not even been *accused*--much less convicted--of having committed any crime, and who have not demonstrated, by any reasonable standard of evidence, to pose a danger to themselves or others.

On the other hand, gun-control advocates have openly pushed to restrict people's rights under such circumstances, making it rather hard to believe that they would not attempt to use any licensing scheme as a tool to make such efforts more effective.

If there were a broad recognition that any government action whose design purpose or substantial effect is to impede any free persons' exercise of their Second Amendment rights is fundamentally illegitimate, and that *government abuse of a licensing scheme would void any requirements for licensure*, then it might be reasonable to discuss licensing proposals.  Unless gun-control advocates will concede that fundamental principle, though, I don't see any basis for any agreement.